# combobox steal keyboard from main window in pyqt

Tags: focus, pyqt, mouseevent, keypress, mousepress

I'm writing a small pyqt program. I want the main window to to react to arrow movement. I added an event to my `MainGui` class, `keyPressEvent`, that handle this. The event work fine as long as I don't press certain buttons such as `Key_Up` or `Key_Down` are directed to my (currently only) `QComboBox` and not to my `mainGui`. I tried to give the focus to `mainGui` after each `paintEvent` but then I need to double click on buttons/comboBox.

Then I tried to use the `MousePressEvent` to check if a certain element is under the mouse. This work fine with the comboBox, but not with the button.

So, how can I direct key events to the `mainGui` or give the focus to `QButtons`?

Answer (score 0):

I used `eventFilter` to identify when the mouse enter the `QPushButton` and give it focus:

```
def eventFilter(self,source,event):
  if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverMove:
     if self.execButton.underMouse():
        self.execButton.setFocus()
        self.keepFocus=False
     else :
        self.keepFocus=True
```

`keepFocus` is a flag I initialized in the `__init__` function of the class. I added this part at the `paintEvent` function

```
    if self.keepFocus:
        self.setFocus()
    else:
        self.keepFocus = True
```

Now, I keep the focus at the `MainGui` and I only give it to the button when the mouse hove over it. If I do another action (like pressing a mouse button or a keyboard key) the focus is given back to the `MainGui`. This will create some buggy filling (For example, I need to press twice a keyboard key before the first response) but this is workable.